# css text at bottom of div / cut white space from below

Tags: css

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1LIf5oy.png]

modifying the line height does not help as it cuts away the part from the top of the text.

any way to align the text at the bottom vertically ? ( vertical-align: text-bottom; does not work )

is there a way to get rid of the whitespace below Discover.

html is:

```
<div class='leftSideNews'> <span class='t1'>Discover</span> <span class='t2'>s world !</span> </div>

.leftSideNews {
    font-size: 20pt;
    /*line-height: 100px;*/
    /*vertical-align: text-bottom;*/
}

.leftSideNews .t1 {
    font-size: 60pt;
    color: #368FD8;
   vertical-align: baseline;
}

.leftSideNews .t2 {
    font-size: 40pt;
    color: #EA3B3B;
}
```

lefSideNews covers both texts. t1 represents the selected text 'Discover' and t2 represents the other red text

EDIT 2: The font i have importated, which is also used in that span is a .toff file, not a .woff file which I am guessing is the root of the problem, as it is not rescaling properly. thanks for your answers.

thanks

Comment: Post your CSS instead of an image

Comment: Do you just want to reduce the size of the padding or margin underneath the line?

Comment: there is no padding or margin, they are set to 0 in parent element and they inherit that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftSideNews .t1 {
   font-size: 60pt;
color: #368FD8;
vertical-align: baseline;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 55px;
background: gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/zvMKH/332/
Is this are you looking for I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, I think that is what he is looking for. Just make the `line-height:65px;` so it displays better.